# How to craft multiple symbols cards as the Vagabond?

Tags: root

I played a bit of this game and the rules are still quite fuzzy for me. The craft rules for the Vagabond tells he can craft if he got a "fresh" hammer and he produces one element of the color of the zone he's in.

Can he stores them and move afterwards to produce an element of another color and then craft the wanted card?

I've checked on boardgamegeek and didn't find answer on the matter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Root FAQ](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1usz2D3BCurx2nKEOtDseCwNaFL7vOArvGHdrIt_KPio/edit):

> **Can I craft cards with multiple-suit requirements?**
>
> No. Your hammers match your current clearing, so you can only craft with one
>   suit at a time. Good news: the multi-suit cards are useless to you
>   anyway!
>
> *Law: 9.2.1*

Comment: Thanks, didn't know this existed !
Even though it's not usefull for us, I thought this could be a good way to annoy another player...